# c++11 - initialize std::string from char* directly with {} constructor

Tags: c++, string, c++11, curly-braces

I have a function which accepts a `std::string&`:

```
void f(std::string& s) { ... }
```

I have a `const char*` which should be the input parameter for that function. This works:

```
const char* s1 = "test";
std::string s2{s};
f(s2);
```

This doesn't:

```
const char* s1 = "test";
f({s1});
```

Why isn't this possible? The funny thing is that CLion IDE is not complaining, but the compiler is:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::basic_string<char>&’
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to work?

Comment: The function expects a string by reference, and your second option is not doing that. In your first example though, `s1` is completely unneeded given your example: `std::string s2 = "test";`

Comment: *The funny thing is that CLion IDE is not complaining, but the compiler is:* -- CLIon is not a compiler.  Compiler wins.

Comment: If you think about it `const char*` is not a `std::string` so for it to even work at all a new temporary string would need to be created to pass to the function. But the function *modifies* the string you pass in!! So it won't accept a temporary. Non-const reference won't bind to temporaries.

Comment: If you need a non-const reference, you cannot pass a temporary anyway.

Comment: Since a `char const*` is not a `std::string`, a conversion occurs. Look at it like this:

    `f({static_cast<string>(s1)});`

The conversion creates a temporary, which cannot bind to an lvalue reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with constructing `std::string` from `char const*`.

`f` expects a lvalue to a string, and by creating a temporary instance on the spot, you're providing an rvalue, which cannot be bound to a non-const lvalue reference. `f(string{})` is just as invalid.

Comment: Well, `f` expects *an lvalue*. Using an lvalue reference parameter is the way you express that in C++, but that doesn't meant hat that "f expects a reference".

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not sure I understand. I thought that the function expects a lvalue reference, and if you pass a lvalue the reference is bound to it.

Comment: You can't really "expect a reference". Functions are called with arguments, arguments are expressions, and expressions are never references. What matters is that the expression is an lvalue. References are a way to *talk about* lvalues.

Comment: @KerrekSB Okay, I changed the wording, is it better now? I will have to educate myself about this.

Comment: Mm, not really. Values don't "refer" to anything. The simple matter of the fact is that "f expects an lvalue of `std::string`", or maybe "a string lvalue". I don't know any better or simpler way of saying that. An lvalue is just a particular kind of value.

Comment: @KerrekSB Okay. I have seen [*lvalue referring*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-1) several times when reading the standard drafts, so I thought it was okay wording. Anyhow, changed yet again, hopefully it's up to par now. Thanks for the corrections

Comment: I suppose. "Designating" is more commonly used, but I figure there's no need for so much language. Sometimes it's possible to be precise and yet straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your function receives a non const reference and you are passing a temporary object, which requires a copy or a const reference parameter. Two solutions, creating another function to receive the object as a rvalue reference and call the other overload within

```
void f(string&& s) {  f(s); }
```

to allow temporary objects as parameter, or change your function definition to receive any object but as a constant reference

```
void f(const std::string& s) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change your function to take a string by value, not by reference. Then it will work. In any case, in C++11 sometimes it's preferable to pass by value, not by reference.